# Executing IIS Express from command line credentials

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I am using VS2015 to start my web application. I would like to be able to run IIS without it if possible to be able to use my app and work with atom or vscode when i want to.

I found the documentation here : http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line

and came out with (I did not specified the site name because it is the first in my config):

```
    iisexpress -config:C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Project\TempProject\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
```

It work fine but when I start the server this way, credentials are required when it is not the case when started from VS2015. To my understanding both VS2015 and this command should run the same thing since they both use the same applicationhost.config.

What am I missing to use it with window authentication like vs2015 seem to do by default.

Thanks